# определение на какие маркеры мы смотрим

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня определяется местоположение пользователя и через CLLocationManager я определяю повороты телефона:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    _userMarker.iconView!.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
    _userMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.9)
    _userMarker.rotation = newHeading.magneticHeading
}
```

Сама _userMaker.iconView - это кратинка в виде конуса. Мне надо определять, что когда наш маркер смотрит на другие маркеры (они попадают в него) мы отображаем одну картинку, а когда нет - другую.

Я пробовал в этом методе обновлять все маркеры, но поскольку их может быть больше 100 - всё ужасно тормозит (ну и вообще сам метод вызывается постоянно, поэтому такой способ очень труднозатратный).

Comment: Как вариант делайте все в другом треде и не при каждом вызове метода, а скажем раз в 30 секунд или же для пользователя очень важно получать моментальный результат при малейшем изменении?

Comment: @VitaliEller именно моментально, в этом-то и проблема(

То есть, если пользователь просто прокрутиться вокруг своей оси, он должен сразу видеть картинки у маркеров на которые смотрит, а потом (когда отворачивается) они должны сразу "прятаться" (там полупрозрачная картинка)

Comment: Можно обновлять не все 100 маркеров, а только те, у которых изменилось состояние.

Comment: Но это же всё равно проверка для каждого маркера нужна. Я просто надеялся, что есть какой-нибудь метод наподобие hittest для маркеров

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант перенесите работу в другой трэд:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
  // тут происходят вычисления
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // тут обновление UI
  }
}
```

В качестве QoS укажите userInteractive, это значит что пользователь должен получать результат как можно быстрее.

И для того, чтобы избежать постоянных расчетов, проверяйте был ли поворот устройства. Смотрите если`heading.magneticHeading` проперти изменила значение, тогда рассчитывайте заново, если нет, то и расчет не нужен.

Comment: но ведь я всё равно буду постоянно вызывать функцию с вычислениями\обновлением UI в отдельной функции, которая будет вызываться при каждом движении телефона, а когда просто держишь телефон в руке - метод didUpdateHeading всё равно обрабатывается (поскольку может банально немного трястись рука)

Comment: воспользуйтесь проперти heading.magneticHeading - она указывает на сторону света, если она нe изменилась, то и нет смысла производить расчеты.

Comment: хм... то есть хранить значение heading.magneticHeading и если оно изменится на 5 (к примеру, это же не сильный поворот), то вызывать функцию... Большое спасибо, попробую!